# How does memory mapping File works in OS?

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

In OS concepts, it states that:
**memory mapping a file, allows a part of the virtual address space to be logically associated with the file**

my concept is:

Usually when a process reads a file on disk using standard system calls open() read() write(), for each file access there is a system call and disk access. which takes time because we are accessing disk.

in this case we can use memory mapped files

in this we virtual memory technique and map the file into the virtual address space of the process.

[image: Memory-Mapped-files]

in this the process will specify to the kernel the file descriptor and the location in it's virtual memory region where it want's to map the file block or blocks (this is a region between heap and stack)

[image: Shared memory mapped]

after that the kernel will map the specific file to the virtual address of the process, the file will be divided into pages. the access to the file will work demand paging. when cpu will generate the virtual address of the page, where the file is mapped to in the processes virtual memory, initially the page will fault and the file page will load from the file system to a free memory frame and the page table of the process will be updated with the frame number in to the page table entry. after that the process can read and write to the file with out accessing the disk but with usual memory access routines.

the writes to the mapped file in the memory is not immediate writes to the file in the disk. some OS periodically the page table entry's dirty bit. when the file is closed all the memory mapped data are written back to the disk and removed from virtual memory of the process.

multiple process also can use page sharing and share memory mapped files between each other.

all they have to do is map there virtual address to the physical address of the mapped file.

***is this how memory mapped files work?***

Comment: what i wanted ask and clearly forgot to add in the question was, that is my concept correct! or do i need to reconsider!

Comment: if you can clarify

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how memory mapping files works. Actually, this is also how memory swap works. You can also read Tanenbaums's "Modern Operation Systems" - it has a whole chapter on memory management, including file mapping. Very clear explanation.

Comment: so this means when the process is created, it has virtual addresses that are empty, and used only when heap or stack grows or in this case when we have to map the file page with it's virtual address space!

Comment: Please don't add new info or answer questions in comments. Rather [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/737085/edit) your original question. That way everything relevant is readily available.